# bootstrap markdown editor parsed html retrieval

Tags: javascript, html, markdown

I use bootstrap-markdown-editor from [here](https://github.com/inacho/bootstrap-markdown-editor) . It is a js editor relying on ace editor. I would like to retrieve the parsed html from the text box to store it in the database, when "submit" is clicked. I looked into the js code of bootstrap-markdown-editor.js and I have no clue where in which propriety is the text saved, nor how to retrieve the parsed html.

The editor is loaded like this:

```
script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $('#editor').markdownEditor({
                preview : true,
                onPreview : function(content, callback) {
                    callback(marked(content));
                }
            });
        });
</script>
```

Does anyone has an idea about how I can access the parsed html from the markdown editor?

Answer (score 0):

Right, I figured it out thanks to another forum. Here is how I recoverd the content of the `textarea` and the marked html (put into `m_html input`) :

```
<script>
        $("#submit_button").on("click", function(){
            const content = $('#editor').val(); 
            document.getElementById("m_html").value = marked(content);  
        });
</script>
```

/cr!ptal